# Weird Xamarin.iOS bug only with Enable debug on (adhoc/release builds)

Tags: ios, xamarin, build, xamarin.ios, pushviewcontroller

I've two weird issues with Xamarin.iOS:

1) NavigationController.PushViewController does work correctly with Debug enabled and NOT with debug disabled.

2) With debug disabled the app crashes after about 60 seconds, but not crash log on the device.

First I noticed the difference between Debug and AdHoc build. But now when I use AdHoc build and turn on 'Enabling debug' it magically works, without further adjustments to settings. Debug symbols are removed and Debug info is set to None.

I saw two other similar questions on this forum and forums.xamarin from a couple of years ago with no answers. I tried different linker and compiler and GC settings on the project but they were not helpful.

Hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one hack to get more information about the crash from a device. Since all your code is executable through mono runtime, you can easily catch lots of crashes by wrapping your UIAplication.Main function into a try-catch block, and save the exception string somewhere on the device.

in Main.cs

```
public class Application {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        try {
            UIApplication.Main(args: args, principalClassName: null, delegateClassName: typeof(AppDelegate).Name);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // save e.ToString() somewhere
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That doesn't catch anything. Feels a bit like iOS just ends the app? With adding the code to test if I written something to disk it changes the bug a bit: now opening a view works once and then stops.

I got some crash logs with this:
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000018c1ff398

And: 
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

Comment: Then I bet it's something wrong with the configuration. Try checking your build options, go through all items and make sure they all the same. Then try to reproduce the issue on debug build. (maybe remove debug check from there, and check if it crash) Debug information has a very little to do with crash, correlation does not mean causation.

Comment: Thanks! This indeed helped me to track down a bug that caused the problem. The cause was some other view being loaded at the same time that caused a view being pushed multiple times.

Comment: @Jørgen Great! :)

Comment: That's neat, but these days there's no need to save it – Xcode has a WiFi Console that works fine with Xamarin apps (Window > Devices and Simulators > "Open Console" button)